# Why is there difference between the basic properties of character arrays and integer arrays in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

If I execute this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char str[20] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    cout<<str<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs `abcde` but If I execute this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[20] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    cout<<arr<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs `0x7fff22eecc30` I have tried executing this code in two different online compilers and they are giving same outputs.

In `char array` it is returning the array contents but in `int array` it's returning memory address. Why is that? Also, how can two different online compilers return the same memory address?

I have tried looking out online for this but I'm not sure what to look for?

Comment: I compiled and executed your code locally and online, but I wasn't able to reproduce your issue, the second example you wrote maybe is `int arr[20]` instead of `char arr[20]`? Can you paste a link to an online ide with your attempt?

Comment: I presume your second example should say `int char[20]`. `cout` looks a the type of the object being passed in. If it is a `char[]`, even through that is a pointer, it will treat it as a string. If it is any other type of pointer, it just prints the address. It's part of cout's operator overloading.

Comment: @Idipaolo @F Trias Sorry! my mistake just changed to that!

Comment: Basic properties of integer arrays and character arrays are the same in C++ (both contain a set of integral values, albeit a `char` can typically represent a smaller set of values than an `int`).Their handling when doing formatted output (e.g. `some_output_stream << some_array`) is different. Each array is converted to a pointer (to `int` or `char`), but the handling from there differs. Output of a `char *` outputs all characters, one at a time, until a terminating nul is found. Output of an `int *` prints the address (value of the pointer, not what it points at), typically in a hex format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `char str[20] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};`, the remaining 15 elements of the array are all set to 0. The special `ostream` overload for `<<` that's used as a result of the array `str` *decaying* to a `char*` pointer to the first element of that array will output the array as if it's a C-style string, since the first 0 will act as a NUL terminator.

An equivalent way of writing the above is `char str[20] = "abcde"`.

In your second case, the overloaded `<<` for `ostream` for a `const void*` pointer is used (due again to pointer decay), which prints the address of the first element of the array.

Comment: why it doesn't print the address in my machine?

Comment: @KeshavGarg: My bad, there's no UB here. It's just that the `ostream` `<<` overload has a special case for `const char*`.

Answer (score 2):

### What `std::cout` knows how to print

Under the hood `cout` is an object derived from the `basic_ostream` class template. The standard library provides some functions that tell `basic_ostream` how to print different types of data. (Some are member functions, some aren't - but that's not important here.)

Here are some examples:

```
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(bool n);
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(short n);
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(int n);
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(double f);
... and more ...
```

These functions tell `cout` (and other basic output streams) how to print bools, shorts, ints, etc.

There's also these two

```
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(const void* p);

template<class traits>
    basic_ostream<char,traits>& 
    operator<<(basic_ostream<char,traits>&, const char*);
```

The first one tells `cout` how to print the address of an untyped pointer (a `void*`).

The second one is intended to print C-style strings --- especially literal strings in your source code. For example, `cout << "Hello";`

### What about arrays?

The standard library *doesn't provide any direct support for printing arrays (or any other collection)*. If you want to print a collection, you have to decide what format you want for that collection, and code it up yourself.

This is the same for structs and classes. If you define your own class, `cout` doesn't know how to print it --- you must code that up yourself.

### Why does your first example output "abcde"?

You're trying to print a `char[20]` (an array of char). `basic_ostream` doesn't have an overloaded << function for arrays, so it doesn't know how to print them.

BUT - C++ is allowed to implicitly cast an "array of T" to a "pointer to T", so your `str` variable is implicitly cast from `char[20]` to `char*`. That matches the last overload I listed above - the one that is *supposed to be used for C-style strings*. (Other answers have already discussed issues regarding the terminating zero that C-strings are supposed to have.)

### What about the second example?

The type of `arr` is `int[20]`. Once again, `cout` doesn't know how to print arrays.

SO - C++ tries implicitly casting your `int[20]` to an `int*`. But there is no overload for `int*`, so C++ tries again. It implicitly casts the `int*` to a `void*` (which it is allowed to do) - and now it finds a match.

The `void*` overload prints the memory address of the pointer.

This happens with all arrays except arrays of `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char`. The array of T is cast down to a pointer to T, which is cast down to a void pointer.

### Why is `char*` treated differently than any other pointer type

Because we print C-style strings (especially string literals) a lot. Like, a lot a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The most often usage of character arrays is the usage them as containers of strings. It is very easy to determine the size of a string due to its sentinel value that is the terminating zero character.

So if in a C program you will write for example

```
char str[20] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
printf( "%s", str );
```

then the call of `printf` easy outputs the string `"abcde"` because it is well-knowb where to stop outputting characters of the character array.

If in a similar call of printf you will specify an integer array then it is unknown  what is the size of the integer array. How many integers stored in the array to output?

So a call of printf for character arrays containing strings is well-defined. However if you are using a pointer of the type `int *` when it is unclear whether the pointer points to a single integer or a sequence of integers. And if the pointer points to a sequence of integers then what is the length of the sequence?

This approach was carried over to the implementation of the overloaded operator << for character arrays in C++.

Pay attention to that if a character array does not contain a string this such a statement

```
std::cout << str;
```

results in undefined behavior. In this case you should use for example the following call

```
std::cout.write( str, sizeof( str ) );
```

Comment: his example has the char array though. wouldn't the list initialisation already add the "\0" after the 4th element? so I am under the impression that it should show whatever the asci values of 1,2,3,4,5 are rather than the mem address.

Comment: @Yucel_K I am confused with that part too. When I use `char arr[20] ={1,2,3,4};` in the code, compiler outputs strange symbols. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: @Yucel_K I have not understood what you wrote.  ASCII values of what?! Of integers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ?

Comment: @KeshavGarg 1,2,3,4 are valid [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character values but they're control characters, not printable symbols.